# How to sort the views by a column from a custom database table?

Tags: views, 9

I have a custom database table `my_apps`.

This table has `nid` and `uid` columns.

I have created a view, which is displaying some nodes. I want to sort this view from that custom table.

Like `ORDER BY COUNT(uid from my_apps) where nid={nid from my_apps}`

Is this possible?

I tried this module [Views custom table](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table) but then you have to create the view based on that table instead of a content view. And I don't want that.

Comment: Probably to create a custom field for views (you can create your own field to be used within views). Have a google for that, there are lots of examples out there

Comment: Can you share a link please?